# Why the form is valide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't the button change color if the form is validated?  If you open the form and send it empty, then for some reason it counts as validated, but if you enter the data, then delete it, then a validation error will appear and the button will not send the data (as it should)

https://jsfiddle.net/qwertyzaqqq/vedhqLsu/12/

https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/BaKBGJY

```js
const showInputError = (formElement, inputElement, errorMessage, settings) => {
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.name}-error`);
  inputElement.classList.add(settings.inputErrorClass);
  errorElement.classList.add(settings.errorClass);
  errorElement.textContent = errorMessage;
}

const hideInputError = (formElement, inputElement, settings) => {
  const errorElement = formElement.querySelector(`#${inputElement.name}-error`);
  inputElement.classList.remove(settings.inputErrorClass);
  errorElement.classList.remove(settings.errorClass);
  errorElement.reset();
}

const hasInvalidInput = (inputList) => {
  return inputList.some((inputElement) => {
    return !inputElement.validity.valid;
  });
}

const toggleButtonState = (inputList, buttonElement, settings) => {
  if (hasInvalidInput(inputList)) {
    buttonElement.classList.add(settings.inactiveButtonClass);
    buttonElement.disabled = true;
  } else {
    buttonElement.classList.remove(settings.inactiveButtonClass);
    buttonElement.disabled = false;
  }
}

const checkInputValidity = (formElement, inputElement, settings) => {
  if (inputElement.validity.valid) {
    hideInputError(formElement, inputElement, settings);
  } else {
    showInputError(formElement, inputElement, inputElement.validationMessage, settings);
  }
}

const setEventListeners = (formElement, settings) => {
  const inputList = Array.from(formElement.querySelectorAll(settings.inputSelector));
  const submitButton = formElement.querySelector(settings.submitButtonSelector);
  inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
    inputElement.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
      checkInputValidity(formElement, inputElement, settings);
      toggleButtonState(inputList, submitButton, settings);
    });
  });
}

const enableValidation = (settings) => {
  const formList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(settings.formSelector));
  formList.forEach((formElement) => {
    setEventListeners(formElement, settings);
  });
}

enableValidation({
  formSelector: '.popup__form',
  inputSelector: '.popup__input',
  submitButtonSelector: '.popup__button',
  inactiveButtonClass: 'popup__save-button_disabled',
  inputErrorClass: 'popup__input_type_error',
  errorClass: 'popup__input-error-message_visible'
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include all of the *relevant* code needed to recreate this error in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see the problem and have the information we need to be able to help you fix it.

Comment: That's by design, default behavior of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Validation not triggered by events

You can add focusout listener to show the validation messages when the person moves to the other input. And/Or add a  keyup event and then check for evt.keycode === 13 and/or 9, if its true the user press the enter/tab keys.

```js
 inputElement.addEventListener('input keyup focusout', (evt) => { <== Add listeners (keyup and focusout)
      checkInputValidity(formElement, inputElement, settings);
      toggleButtonState(inputList, submitButton, settings);
    });
```

The check for enter/tap keys would look somewhat like this.

```js
   inputElement.addEventListener('input keyup focusout', (evt) => {
   if(evt.keycode === 13 || evt.keycode === 9){ // The Enter and Tab keyup check
          checkInputValidity(formElement, inputElement, settings);
          toggleButtonState(inputList, submitButton, settings);
          }
 });
```

Comment: I am sorry , but i really dont know how to fix it then. I only started to js. I did it with the instruction

Comment: I have added an explanation how to fix this issue. Tell me if you need any more help

Comment: the button still inactive if form validate is true

Comment: https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/BaKBGJY  this is all

Comment: This should help you trigger the validation messages, there are still many errors in your code though.

Comment: I load a new cod in codpen.

Comment: okay. Ill start to remake my code. i really see many errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
errorElement.reset();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).